# jQuery autocomplete on / off functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on website (built using PHP, MySQL, jQuery) which require that admin set a variable in configuration and according to that configuration variable jQuery autocomplete is enabled or disabled to all website.

Is there any way to achieve that functionality?

Comment: do you use template engine etc. smarty, dwoo ?

Comment: No I an not using any template. I am just want to set a variable globally in my website and all autocomplete box disable

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set a variable on the header, end of the body, or wherever you need to

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var autocomplete= '.$configuration['autocomplete'].';
</script>';
```

and work it from there.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply.

I have tried your script, but still autocomplete box appears with values.

I have write below code in index.php
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js?nocache=<?= getVersion () ?>"></script>

<script>
var autocomplete= 'false';
</script>

I just want to set a variable globally in my website and all autocomplete box disable.

Please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

ok, you have some initialization function there, so check if autocomplete must be on/off in that function and not initialize that what you need, or do it. i dont see any problems to realize here..

```
function profiles_autocompletes_init(mode){

        ....check it here.... :)

    $("#"+mode+"ProfileSelecter").autocomplete("/autocomplete/profiles/", {
        ...
    }); 
}
```